# How to use inner camera in gltf in aframe?

Tags: camera, aframe, gltf

I have a gltf model, which contains cameras, models and camera animations. After loading, they become an gltf entity. I can't use `secondcamera el. SetAttribute ('camera ','active', true ')"` to change camera. How can I use the camera in it.

This can be modified in three. JS

```
this.content.traverse((node) => {

if (node.isCamera && node.name === name) {

this.activeCamera = node;

}

});

this.renderer.render( this.scene, this.activeCamera )
```

but, how to use inner camera in gltf in aframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could keep the reference to the camera:

```
var model_camera = null;
// wait until the model is loaded
entity.addEventListener("model-loaded", e => {
  const mesh = entity.getObject3D("mesh");
  mesh.traverse(node => {
    // assuming there is one camera
    if (node.isCamera) model_camera = node;
  })
})
```

and when you need to use it, just substitute the active camera in the [scene.camera property](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/core/scene.html#properties_camera):

```
entity.sceneEl.camera = model_camera;
```

Check it out in [this example](https://gftruj.github.io/webzamples/aframe/gltf_cameras/) with a model containing two different cameras.

---

Afaik there is no cleanup involved, the `look-controls` or `wasd-controls` will still be working as long as you don't manually disable them when switching cameras.

The [camera system](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/src/systems/camera.js#L147) has a function for swapping active cameras, but you would need to add `<a-entity>` wrappers for the camera references (as the system tries to perform `getObject3D('camera')` on the provided entity).